# QGIS Profile Tool displaying inconsistent horizontal axis values

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-plugins, profile

I am analyzing stream channel gradients on Mars. The workflow is essentially to grab a Mars DEM from the HiRISE website, reproject it into ASU's preferred Mars 2000 CRS, use the SAGA Basic Terrain Analysis tool in QGIS to extract a vector layer for inferred stream channels, and then use the Profile Tool to create a csv file for the elevations along those channels.

Here's the issue I wanted to share with you: This whole process worked well for me when I tested it with the horizontal axis running from 0 to about 55,000 m.
[image: This first plot displays the profile with correct elevations and correct streamwise distances]

When my student attempted to reproduce these results, they got a plot with the same elevation values and plot shape, but with a horizontal axis that goes from 0 to 1.
[image: This second plot has the same elevations but the horizontal axis (units unknown) ranges from 0 to 1.]

One other piece of evidence that demonstrates a difference in how measurements are being made in their project is that when the measurement tool is used to find straight-line distances on the DEM, they gets very small numbers (<< 1) in Cartesian and accurate measurements in Ellipsoidal. My project yields accurate numbers in Cartesian and "nan" in Ellipsoidal.

A couple of the things I looked at while troubleshooting were the parameters used to define the coordinate system and the Project Properties > General > Measurements settings. I verified that these are the same for my project and my student's project.

What are some other actions to explore with the student's project to get an accurate Profile?

Comment: Is the student using the same Project CRS as you are?

Comment: Thanks for your question, Kasper. That is the first thing we checked. Yes, both CRS's are the same.

Comment: Ok.Still an obvious question sorry,  I don't have any strong clue : are both DEM layers for sure in the same CRS (layer properties)